# Camera auto capture when hold the phone?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am developing an Android app that has a surface-view and I want to capture the image when the user holds the phone steady for 2 to 3 seconds. What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "the user hold the phone in 2-3s" means.

Comment: I mean on start user will move the camera to find an object. After that, when the object is in viewport and the camera don't move in 2-3s, an image is captured.

Comment: So basically you are asking how to detect movement/ the end of movement? Or would you like to have some help in having the device take a picture? If you have more than one problem, then please consider breaking down your question into smaller packages and try to solve one problem at a time. - Anyway, we can help you better if you show us some sample code of what you have tried so far.